# how to find the minimum of several dates in PSPP

Tags: date, min, pspp

I'm trying to extract **the minimal date out of several date columns** in **PSPP**.
Here is the syntax file I'm using:

```
***************************************
* [1] READ FORM CSV FILE :: input.csv *
***************************************
GET DATA
/TYPE=TXT
/FILE='input.csv'
/FIRSTCASE=2
/VARIABLES=
startDate1 ADATE8
endDate1   ADATE8
startDate2 ADATE8
endDate2   ADATE8
startDate3 ADATE8
endDate3   ADATE8
startDate4 ADATE8
endDate4   ADATE8
.

***********************************
* [2] DEFINE VARIABLE :: earliest *
***********************************
Variable earliest:
COMPUTE earliest = MIN(startDate1,startDate2,startDate3,startDate4).
EXECUTE.

**************************************
* [3] SAVE TO CSV FILE :: output.csv *
**************************************
SAVE TRANSLATE
/OUTFILE='output.csv'
/REPLACE
/TYPE=CSV
```

When I examine `output.csv` I see that a new column was indeed created,
but instead of an mm/dd/yyyy pattern it's just some 11 digits numbers.
Any help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally found it. Not so straight forward, but still working.
The catch is that you have to convert a date to an integer and only then
take the minimum value.

```
***************************************
GET DATA
/TYPE=TXT
/FILE='input.csv'
/FIRSTCASE=2
/VARIABLES=
startDate1 ADATE8
endDate1   ADATE8
startDate2 ADATE8
endDate2   ADATE8
startDate3 ADATE8
endDate3   ADATE8
startDate4 ADATE8
endDate4   ADATE8
.

*******************************************************************
Variable myDate1:
COMPUTE myDate1=XDATE.YEAR(startDate1)*1000+XDATE.JDAY(startDate1).
EXECUTE.
*******************************************************************
Variable myDate2:
COMPUTE myDate2=XDATE.YEAR(startDate2)*1000+XDATE.JDAY(startDate2).
EXECUTE.
*******************************************************************
Variable myDate3:
COMPUTE myDate3=XDATE.YEAR(startDate3)*1000+XDATE.JDAY(startDate3).
EXECUTE.
*******************************************************************
Variable myDate4:
COMPUTE myDate4=XDATE.YEAR(startDate4)*1000+XDATE.JDAY(startDate4).
EXECUTE.
*******************************************************************
Variable earliest:
COMPUTE earliest = MIN(myDate1,myDate2,myDate3,myDate4).
EXECUTE.

**************************************
SAVE TRANSLATE
/OUTFILE='output.csv'
/REPLACE
/TYPE=CSV
```